# How to hide infrequently used menu items in .net windows forms application?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

Most folks will know the behavior of ms office applications menus: When opening a menu, the user at first only sees the menu items which are used frequently. Hovering over the menu with the cursor or clicking on a small "arrows" symbol expands the menu to show all items. Still the formerly hidden items have a lighter background color. When a menu item is selected, it is added to the selection of instantly shown menu items for the next use of the menu.

How do you implement this in your own .net 3.5 windows forms application? Are there tools out there to use or do we have to implement it by ourselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Visual Studio Magazine [article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2007/07/01/Implement-Expandable-Menus.aspx?Page=1) about a method for doing expandable menus. Seems like implementing it yourself but that it shouldn't be too difficult.